# Code only outputting first line of string to text file? (Python3)

Tags: python-3.x, praw

My code looks like this:

```
import praw

reddit = praw.Reddit(

client_id= "Client ID is filled but don't want to share it",

client_secret = "Client Secret is filled but don't want to share it",

user_agent = "ShowerThoughts" )


for submission in reddit.subreddit("showerthoughts").hot(limit=10):
       submission.title
       file1 = open("myfile.txt","w")
       file1.write(submission.title)
       file1.close() #to change file access modes
```

The problem is when I check it in myfile.txt. It only prints one line of it. It looks likes its printing the last line of it only. I don't want to redirect the output from the terminal to a text file. I want it to be included in the python file.

Comment: When you open a file in `w` mode, it _erases any old contents!_ Now that you know this, what change would you make so that the contents from the previous iteration don't get erased in the current iteration?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to open and close the file ten times. The write `"w"` mode means you will overwrite whatever is in it. Either use the append `"a"` mode if the file already exists, or open the file only once and write all the titles in it directly.

```
with open("myfile.txt", "w") as file:
    for submission in reddit.subreddit("showerthoughts").hot(limit=10):
        file.write(submission.title)
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked. But is there any way to make spaces between the lines like how it does in the output. Currently it's just putting them all together with no spaces.

Comment: Of course. `file.write(submission.title + "\n")`

Comment: Wow! thank you so much. Is there a way to give awards on this platform like reddit?

Comment: I don't think so but don't worry about it. Glad to help ;)